# How to prove that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I have to prove that $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$. I used the definition of a derivative:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$
Using angle sum formula:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\sin (x)\cos (h)+\cos (x)\sin (h)-\sin (x)}{h}$$
Rearranging the terms:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos (h)\sin(h)-\sin(x)+\sin(x)\cos(h)}{h}$$
Factoring out $\sin(x)$ from the last two terms:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos(x)\sin(h)-\sin(x)[1-\cos(h)]}{h}$$
Separating the fraction:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos(x)\sin(h)}{h}-\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x)[1-\cos(h)]}{h}$$
Now I am stuck. Can anyone please tell me what to do next, or give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: That should be $\sin(x)[1-\cos (h)]$.

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$$

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8d.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it depends on what you know.  Do you have $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\sin h}h=1$?  And $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {1-\cos h}h=0$?  Then insert them and you are done.  These usually come before what you are doing.  The Taylor series are another route, but usually come later.

Comment: This is not homework; I am just studying this on my own. No I do not know the limits you have written about

Comment: Then basically you need to prove those.  I don't know any other way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151) for a geometric proof that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1
$$
You might also find the following useful:
$$
\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}
$$